# moment.js - diff in minutes returns incorrect value

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have two variable populated with datetime - one containing value from cookie (utc), the otherone containing current time in utc:

```
var expiration = moment(Date.parse($.cookie("ecookie"))); 
var current = moment().utc();

console.log(current.format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
console.log(expiration.format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
```

output showing values in variables:

May 20th 2022, 2:17:37 pm

May 20th 2022, 3:14:11 pm

**Why is the diff method returning value 63 (time difference in minutes) ?:**

```
current.diff(expiration, "minutes") // 63
```

**It should be under 60 minutes. What piece am I missing ?**

**EDIT:**

**Storing the cookie value in ISO 8601 format solves the issue**

Comment: The two dates you posted are exactly 63 minutes and 26 seconds apart are they not? What are you expecting as output here?

Comment: I am expecting 56 minutes 34 seconds @CollinD

Comment: you're right, I misread the dates. That said, running your code in runkit produces the expected output of 56. Maybe you haven't posted enough to show the problem?

Comment: ```var moment = require("moment");

var expiration = moment("2022-05-20T14:17:37"); 
var current = moment("2022-05-20T15:14:11"); 

console.log(current.format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
console.log(expiration.format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));

current.diff(expiration, "minutes") // 56```

works.

Comment: It probably has to do something of how date is stored in the cookie 
cookie content: "'5/20/2022 3:14:11".
I can not see other place that might cause the issue... just idk

Comment: The only major issues I see then are `Date.parse` is going to parse that date as an AM time in your local time zone. `moment().utc()` will be in UTC.  Try storing your cookie as ISO 8601 including tz and see if it works?

Comment: Populating the cookie (on .net backend  - DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o")) with value in ISO 8601 format solved the issue.  @CollinD thx mate